# How to understand capacitor reading: 0.1uF + 2x2500pF?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

I have an old electrical motor from the 1970s. It does not work as it should, and I suspect the capacitor attached to it. It has two legs and reads: 0.1uF+2x2500pF ~250v. I am not familiar with that "+2x2500pF" way of writing it. What should my multimeter read when measuring and what is the idea of the way to write its capacitance? Currently imy multimeter reads something like 0.177uF when connected to the two legs.

[image]

Comment: Is there a third connection to the capacitor that looks different? For example, it might be attached to the chassis with a nut.

Comment: There are two cords coming from the capacitor, those were the ones I measured between. But yes, you are right. The capacitors body is made of alloy and it is attached to the motor with a bolt. So it could be that is a "3rd leg"

Comment: Also, just updated the question with a "2x" notation I left out by mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fldpTj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The internal arrangement.*

C2 and C3 shunt high frequency noise to ground.

> What should my multimeter read when measuring and what is the idea of the way to write its capacitance? Currently my multimeter reads something like 0.177 uF when connected to the two legs.

Your multimeter reading looks about right. Electrolytics have a very wide tolerance on the capacitance value. The motor fault may be something else.

Comment: Is this kind of capacitor electrolytic? If it is, it would be an unpolarized one, right? Non-electrolytics also have a wide tolerance.

Comment: It's not electrolytic at such a small value from that period. Paper in oil ("Visconol") was commonly used for 0.1uF : check DC resistance > 10Meg (and to case), they did develop some leakage current.